# how to count Name in Mongodb with $lookup

Tags: arrays, mongodb

This is example of the joint
[image]

I want to count the number of names and I use the lookup and this is my Syntax:

```
 db.o_event_entity.aggregate([
 {"$lookup":{
 "from":"o_user_entity",
 "localField":"USER_ID",
 "foreignField":"ID",
 "as":"doc"}},
 {"$unwind":"$doc"},
  {"$group":{
  "_id":{"name":"$doc.FIRST_NAME", total:{$sum:"$doc.FIRST_NAME"}}}}
    ])
```

And this is result
[image]

What I do to count the total number of name

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
      db.collection.aggregate([
     {"$lookup":{
    "from":"first_collection",
    "localField":"PK",
    "foreignField":"FK",
     "as":"doc"}},
    {"$unwind":"$doc"},
    {"$group":{
    "_id":{"name":"$doc.FIRST_NAME", "last":"$doc.LAST_NAME"},
     "total":{$sum:1}}}
      ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the string `$doc.FIRST_NAME` as the value that [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) should sum together. You need to provide a numeric value. Since you're interested only in count, you can just provide `1`.

```
total: { $sum: 1 }
```